# Pivoting table with non-integer values without aggregate function

Tags: sql-server

I need to get results based on occupations with names in the rows. Below is the structure of a sample data.

```
create table Employees (name varchar(10), occupation varchar(12))

Insert into Employees values ('Member1','Doctor')
Insert into Employees values ('Member2','Doctor')
Insert into Employees values ('Member3','Lawyer')
Insert into Employees values ('Member4','Teacher')
Insert into Employees values ('Member5','Lawyer')
Insert into Employees values ('Member6','Teacher')
Insert into Employees values ('Member7','Lawyer')
```

As per my understanding it is achivable with PIVOT in sql server but it needs some aggregate function and i can use MAX which will give MAX(value1)=value1
I tried below query :

```
Select * from 
(Select name,occupation from Employees) as emp
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(name) for occupation in (Doctor,Teacher,Lawyer)
) as pvt
```

It is giving me result as

```
Doctor  Teacher Lawyer
Member2 Member6 Member7
```

But I need result in below structure as columns are in ascending order

```
Doctor  Teacher Lawyer
Member1 Member4 Member3
Member2 Member6 Member5
NULL    NULL    Member7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day,

Please check this solution:

```
Select * 
from (
    Select 
        [name],[occupation], 
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [occupation] order by [name],[occupation])
    from Employees
) t
PIVOT (
    MAX(name) for occupation in (Doctor,Teacher,Lawyer)
) as pvt
```

Comment: It worked as expected. I tried it with DENSE_RANK() function but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

use `ROW_NUMBER()` function and try below way

```
 Select * 
    from (
        Select 
            name,occupation, 
            Row_num = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by [occupation] order by [name],[occupation])
        from Employees
    ) t
    PIVOT (
        MAX(name) for occupation in (Doctor,Teacher,Lawyer)
    ) as pvt
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/41f11/1

```
Row_num Doctor  Teacher Lawyer
1       Member1 Member4 Member3
2       Member2 Member6 Member5
3      (null)   (null)  Member7
```